# Wrapping textbox text in a button-like UI element

Tags: html, user-interface

Sorry for the strange title: because I don't know what this effect is called I have no idea how to search for it via Google or on Stack Overflow...

An example of what I'm trying to describe can be found on the Yahoo Mail "compose message screen." When you finish entering an email address (or select an auto-complete suggestion) the text of the email address in the "To:" box has a style applied that makes it look like a button:

[image]

1. What is the name of this effect?
2. Where can I find a reference as to how to duplicate it?

Comment: andyzinsser provided a link to a resource for how to do this... does anyone know what this is properly called though? I would like to update the title of this question appropriately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like it will work for you.
http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/#tags

Comment: This is PRECISELY what I'm looking for! Still have no clue what to call it... awesome that someone can help me find it even without knowing the proper name.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the effect is formally called but I've recently done something similar.

I wrote it as a jquery plugin.

The basic gist is create a div and a textbox that fills it.
Listen for character events on the text box and on tab/return create a new div to the left of the text box with the text you want to show. In js you can measure the width of the rendered div and position the text input to the right.

I also made it so escape key cleared all the labels/keywords 
Pressing enter with an empty text input fired an event, like a submisssion
And clicking on a label replaced the div with a text input to allow the user to modify the label in place

I'm on iPad at mo so don't have sample, but hope that points you in write direction.